# Why does Fody weaving fail to weave other projects?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, fody, fody-costura

Sorry for the use of pictures here but it seemed appropriate.

I have a simple method interceptor working in the first image, but when I move my interceptor to be a part of the library that I want it to live in (for reusability) it just stops weaving.

Fody weaving working
[image: Fody weaving working]

Fody weaving not working
[image: Fody weaving not working]

Comment: Try to add `[module: Interceptor]` to the `FodyTest` project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding [module: Interceptor] to the FodyTest project was the solution to the issue.

A change since fody version 3 makes this necessary in the newer fody.

Thanks for the tip Lucas Trzesniewski